# Removing sequential repeating items from List in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm looking for a way in Kotlin to prevent repeating items in a list but still preserve the order. For example

```
  val list = listOf(ObjectMock(1,"a"), ObjectMock(2,"c"), ObjectMock(3,"c"),
        ObjectMock(4,"a"), ObjectMock(4,"c"), ObjectMock(4,"c"), ObjectMock(1,"a")
        , ObjectMock(1,"c"), ObjectMock(2,"c"), ObjectMock(3,"c"), ObjectMock(4,"a")
        , ObjectMock(2,"b") )
```

should become

```
result = listOf(ObjectMock(1,"a"), ObjectMock(2,"c"), ObjectMock(3,"c"),
            ObjectMock(4,"a"), ObjectMock(1,"a") , ObjectMock(2,"c"), ObjectMock(3,"c"), ObjectMock(4,"a")
            , ObjectMock(2,"b") )
```

I'm using a for loop and check next item then add it to different list but Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: @Crispert LinkedHashSet would generate `1,2,3,4` and not the required `1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 2):

this is another way to do it

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 )
val result = list.fold(emptyList<Int>()){acc, i ->
    if (acc.lastOrNull() != i) acc + i else acc
}
```

Comment: It works fine with integers but when it comes to objects it doesn't work I updated my question hope if you can help with that

Comment: @Amin it should work with other objects as well. Just replace <Int> with <ObjectMock>. At least if identical objects return false on the if-check

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Kotlin Flows

```
viewModelScope.launch {
        list.asFlow()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .collect {
                Log.d(TAG, "distict numbers: $it")
            }
    }
```